# Intro analysis question related to MVT

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, derivatives

> Q) Let $f$ be a real-valued function which is continuous in a
>   neighbourhood $N$ of some point $c∈R$. Suppose that $f$ is
>   differentiable on N\ {c} and that $\lim_{x->c} f'(x)=L$. Show that $f$
>   is differentiable at $c$ with $f'(c) = L$.

My try: $f$ is differentiable at $c$ if the limit $\lim_{x->c+}(f(x)-f(c))/(x-c)$ exists. As $f$ is differentiable in $(c, c+h)$, from MVT, there is some $y\in (c, c+h)$ such that interval such that $f'(y)=\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{c+h-c}=L$. This implies that: $\lim_{x->c} f'(y)=\lim_{x->c} L = f'(c)=L$.

I know this isn't correct, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Well, the MVT tells you there is a $y$ in $(c,x)$ with $f’(y) = \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$, but you do not know that this quotient (or that derivative) has value exactly $L$. You don’t know that because all you know is that $f’(x)$ **approaches** $L$, as you approach $c$, not that it is **equal** to $L$. So instead you want to show that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ you can find $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt x-c\lt \delta$, then $(f(x)-f(c))/(x-c)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $L$. And you know you can make sure that $f’(y)$ is that close to $L$ for any $y$ sufficiently close to $c$, so...

Comment: Also, you need more than just the limit as $x\to c^+$ to exist and have the correct value; that only gives you the right derivative. You’ll need to do the same thing for $x\to c^-$.

Comment: You have the right idea (+1 there) but you need to develop it more rigorously as done in some of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

$f'(y)=L$ is not correct.

Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $\delta >0$ such that $|f'(y)-L| <\epsilon$ for $|x-c| < \delta$. Then for suitable $y$ we get  $|\frac {f(c+h)-f(c)} h -L|=|f'(y)-L|<\epsilon$ for $|x-c| < \delta$.

Answer (score 1):

1) Let $x >c$.

$\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(t)$ , $c <t< x$.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow c^+} t= c$, hence

$\lim_{x \rightarrow c^+} \dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=$

$\lim_{t \rightarrow c^+}f'(t)=L$;

2) Likewise for $x <0$.

3) 1)and 2) imply $f$ differentiable at $c$, and $f'(c)=L$.

A bit formal:

0) $x >c$;

1) Need to show :

For $\epsilon >0$ given,

there is a $\delta$ s.t.

$0<x-c<\delta$ implies $|\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-L|<\epsilon$.

2) We have

$\lim_{ t \rightarrow c^+}f'(t)=L$, i.e.

there is a $\delta_1$ s.t.

$0<t-c<\delta_1$ implies $|f'(t)-L|<\epsilon.$

Let $\delta=\delta_1$; then for

$0<x-c < \delta$ we have

$|\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-L|=$

$|f'(t)-L|<\epsilon$,

since $\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = f'(t)$ , $0<t-c<x-c$.

3) Consider $x \rightarrow c^-$  and complete the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use de l'Hospital rule, whose hypotheses are satisfied in the right neighboorhood $N^+$ and left neighboorhood $N^-$ of $c$, so that
$$\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\stackrel{H}{=}\lim_{x\to c^+}f'(x)=L,$$
and 
$$\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\stackrel{H}{=}\lim_{x\to c^-}f'(x)=L.$$
Hence, the thesis.

Comment: While this is correct and a valid use of L'Hospital's Rule (+1), the exercise is probably meant to demonstrate the importance of mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Using sequences is quite comfortable here.

Choose in $N$ any sequence $x_n \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\rightarrow} c$ ($x_n \neq c$ for all $n$)

MVT tells you, that for each $x_n$ there is $\xi_n$ with
$$\frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n -c}= f'(\xi_n) \mbox{ s.t.  } 0 < |\xi_n - c| < |x_n - c|$$

If follows $\xi_n \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\rightarrow} c$ and 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n -c} = \lim_{n\to \infty} f'(\xi_n) =L$$.